# update panel does not work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

im trying to get the value of a dropdownlist and insert it into a label inside an update panel like the following:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpTutorialDropDown" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="TutorialSeries" DataTextField="SeriesName" DataValueField="VideoSeriesNameID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList><br />
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TutorialSeries" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" SelectCommand="ViewSeasonName" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:Label ID="lblEpisode" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxURL" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxDiscription" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and in code behind i have

```
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblEpisode.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
```

but i dont know why it doesnt update the label!! the text of the label remains the same!!! can someone spot the problem??

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the trigger to get something like so

```
<br />
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="TutorialSeries" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" SelectCommand="ViewSeasonName" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpTutorialDropDown" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="TutorialSeries" DataTextField="SeriesName" DataValueField="VideoSeriesNameID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Label ID="lblEpisode" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxURL" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxDiscription" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    </ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: if i remove the  trigger then i should put the dropdownlist inside the update panel which that wont work still

Comment: Are you using the "uploader" form ? This form is known to have a conflict with the update panel .

Answer (score 0):

You have to put drop down list into existing Update panel as well...

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `Update()` method of the update panel in your Event as shown below.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblEpisode.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    udpTutorialDropDown.Update();
}
```

All the best!

**UPDATE**

You must add `AutoPostBack="true"` property in the drop down list. And, ignore my previous instructions. I.e. calling the Update() method of the update panel. That's required only when you have `UpdateMode="Conditional"`

This should work :)

Comment: why should i update my dropdownlist?? im trying to get the value from it and pass it to label!! also when i change the SelectedIndexChanged to DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged ill get the following error: 
Could not find an event named 'DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged' on associated control 'DropDownList1' for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'udpTutorialDropDown'

Comment: You are not updating your DDL, you are updating the content/ controls within the update panel. Yeah, my mistake it should be EventName="SelectedIndexChanged", sorry

Comment: And, if your update panel is not within another update panel you'll have to set it's UpdateMode property. E.g. UpdateMode="Conditional"

Comment: actually it is inside another update panel. as in there is a main update panel which it i load a ascx file in it and inside the ascx file i have the update panel "udpTutorialDropDown"

Comment: Then you won't need UpdateMode="Conditional". Just call .Update() method within the event handler. Have a try

Comment: thanks a lot for reply sam. actually i figured it out yesterday and i removed udpTutorialDropDown.Update(); from code behind and i added AutoPostBack="true". but again something went wrong. as i said before i have updatepanel2 inside updatepanel1 and in updatepanel2 i have the label and drobdownlist. the updatepanel1 has UpdateMode="Conditional" and when i added AutoPostBack="true" to the updatepanel2, the label gets updated when i choose something in dropdownlist but that only works if its used for the first time! if i choose something else in updatepanel1 then come back, it wont work!

Comment: Can you add the code with two panels and their code behind to have a look?